# Сортировка листа со сложным объектом по вложенному полю в обратном порядке

Tags: c#, linq

Что-то не получается отсортировать лист со сложным объектом, вроде все правильно делаю, но список получается не сортированным.

```
List.groupby(x=>x.name).orderby(x => x.key.count()).reverse().toarray()
```

Подскажите в чем проблема может быть? Или как здесь отлаживать код? Никогда **linq** не отлаживал.

Ps Писал по памяти с планшета, мог немного ошибиться в названиях

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что Вы сортировали по количеству символов в имени. Попробуйте так:

```
List.groupby(x=>x.name).orderby(x => x.Count()).Reverse().ToArray()
```

Если разобраться, то выяснится, что при группировке создается класс, реализующий интерфейс IGrouping<TKey,TElement> расширяющий IEnumerable<TElement>. Таким образом, если вы хотите обратиться к ключу, то используете x.Key, а перебрать последовательность можно и так:

```
foreach (var item in x){}
```

Таким образом, чтобы посчитать элементы группы нужно использовать x.Count() вместо x.Key.Count().

Answer (score 0):

Операция GroupBy группирует элементы последовательности в соответствии с заданной функцией селектора ключа и возвращает [`IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb344977(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

В вашем случае Вы обращаетесь к ключу и сортируете по количеству символов в нем.

> orderby(x => x.key.count())

Для сортировки по количеству элементов в группе, необходимо использовать

```
OrderBy(x => x.Count())
```

---

Чтобы не использовать `Reverse` можно сразу сортировать в обратном порядке, т.е. в порядке убывания. Для этого в **LINQ** есть метод [OrderByDescending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb548916(v=vs.110).aspx)